# How does fgets treat enter key press?

Tags: c, fgets

What I am seeing is that while accepting a string - fgets takes the string till an enter key is pressed, and in the end it DOES NOT replace the enter key with \0 - rather appends \0 to the string including enter key.
In comparison, gets_s takes the string till enter key is pressed and in the end - replaces the last enter key with \0.

Is this correct. Please add, correct, confirm.
Also does this mean. my string handling operations that operate character by character till they encounter a \0 - will now - with fgets - operate on a newline character as well ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

    char i[32];

    printf("Enter a string of size 32 or less characters \n");
    gets_s(i, sizeof(i));
    //fgets(i, sizeof(i), stdin);

    printf("With right justification, field width = 32 and precision = 10 -> i = ||%32.10s||\n", i);
    printf("With left justification, field width = 32 and precision = 10 -> i = ||%-32.10s||\n", i);
    printf("With right justification, field width = 10 and precision = 32 -> i = ||%10.32s||\n", i);
    printf("With left justification, field width = 10 and precision = 32 -> i = ||%-10.32s||\n", i);


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your analysis of the behavior of `fgets()` and `gets_s()` is correct.  It's usually stated that both of them add a trailing `'\0'` to the string, but that `fgets()` also includes the trailing newline as well.  As for how to handle this, that's largely up to you.  A common pattern is to strip the trailing newline from the input if you're using `fgets()`.

Comment: This behavior is described in the manual https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: Another nice trick for stripping the newline is `strtok(line, '\n')`.

Comment: I prefer a more 'fool proof' method of stripping (a possible) trailing newline by:  `char input[ 1024];  fgets( input, sizeof( input), stdin );  input[ strcspn( input, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2):

> How does fgets treat enter key press?

Just like any other key, other than it is 1 of 4 reasons to stop reading more.

---

" fgets takes the string till an enter key is pressed, " is a causal explanation.

Let us go deeper

`char *fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream);` does not read a *string* as C defines a *string* (characters up to and including the *null character*).  `fgets()` reads a *line* of characters (characters up to and including the `'\n'`).  It reads them up to a certain point - leaving the rest for later.

1. A `'\n'` is read (and saved).
2. The input buffer is nearly full.  (all but 1)
3. End of file occurs.
4. Rare input error occurs.

In cases 1, 2 and 3 (if at least something was read), a *null character* is appended to the input.  Now the input is certainly a *string* and the function return `s`.  In other cases the function returns `(char *) NULL`.

Note the if `fgets()` reads *null characters*, they are treated like any other non-`'\n'`.

---

<kbd>Enter</kbd> causes `'\n'`:  That is a character too.

The `'\n'` might need to be discarded for later processing.  In that case simply lop it off.  Since the input might not contain `'\n'`, robust code does not rely on its presence.  Nor does robust code assume the first character is not a *null character*.

```
size_t len = strlen(s);
if (len > 0 && s[len-1] == '\n') {
  s[--len] = '\0';
}

// OR

s[strcspsn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

OP's explanation of `gets_s()` has similar detail missing in OP's desciption: special functionality on buffer full, end-of-file and error.